# toggleClass in jQuery skips css rule

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div of `id="header"` with initial css rule: `padding: 25px 0;`. When scrolling down the page, I want to decrease this div's padding:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var headerID = $("#header");
  $(this).scroll(function() {
    if (!$(this).scrollTop()) 
      headerID.toggleClass("headerScrolled");
    else if (!headerID.is(".headerScrolled")) 
      headerID.toggleClass("headerScrolled");
  });
});
```

```css
.headerScrolled {
  padding: 15px 0;
}
```

However when I scroll down the page, padding does not change. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: you're running same code on both if-else conditions? What the purpose of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your two conditions are cancelling each other out. It makes more sense to make a single call to `toggleClass()` and provide the boolean argument to specify if the class should be added or removed based on the current `scrollTop` value. Also note that you should listen for the scroll on the `window` instead of the `document`. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $header = $("#header");

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $header.toggleClass('headerScrolled', $(this).scrollTop() !== 0);
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  padding: 25px 0;
  background-color: #CCC;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
#header.headerScrolled {
  padding: 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  Header
</div>
```

Comment: This solution will keep toggling the `headerScrolled` class on header as the content is scrolled

Comment: That's not the case. I added a snippet to demonstrate

Comment: Awesome as usual, never knew you could pass a bool into toggleClass, this will make a lot of things much easier from now on!

Comment: Same. Please edit this to include instructions on using `window` instead of `this` for the scroll method and I'll upvote and remove my answer.

Comment: @sean thank you, but there's no need for you to remove your answer.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Why this solution won't work as you emit the "#header" from the #header.headerScrolled css selector?

Comment: You need to make the `.headerScrolled` selector more specific in order to override any existing styling on the element. That's why I included `#header` on that selector.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `.scroll()` method on `window`, not `this` or the `document`. Additionally, it may be easier to use `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` in this case.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $header = $("#header");

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if (!$(window).scrollTop()) {
      $header.addClass("headerScrolled");
    } else {
      $header.removeClass("headerScrolled");
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: This solution will keep toggling the class on #header